# How can I reach content of href tag in AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am learning AJAX and I have one question. In html file I have an image:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" title="<?php echo $image; ?>" onClick="javascript:ajax_post();return false" >
    <img src="foto.php?file=<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="building thumb"/>
</a>
```

Then I have AJAX function. I tried it on basic input example and everything worked OK. Now my question is how can I reach "title" in AJAX function.

```
function ajax_post(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
    var title = ($(this).attr("title")); // This is not working...
    alert(title); // Title is unidentified.
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(title);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why you don't simply pass title ajax_post() function ?

Comment: You need to reference on DOM element which raised event using `this`, Here example, `onClick="javascript:ajax_post(this);return false"` and then use the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = $(".show_hide").attr("title"); //
```